# What were the details of the claim that "Highlander: The Source" events were just a dream?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

> And the fifth movie has been retconned into "All Just a Dream" [trope] via *Word Of God*
>   *(from TVTrope's "[Canon discontinuity](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanonDiscontinuity)" article on "Highlander: The Source" movie).*

What exactly was that Word of God that claimed that *The Source* was just a dream?

Comment: What fifth movie? Everyone knows there have only been 3 Highlander movies, namely 1, 3, and 4. ;)

Comment: If we all believe enough, maybe the fifth movie will just go away.  The guardian was a kind of cool idea though.  Poorly executed, but kinda cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's no indication that "[Highlander : The Source](http://highlander.wikia.com/wiki/Highlander%3a_The_Source)" has been "disavowed" by either Gregory Widen (the original creator of Highlander) or Peter S. Davis (who produced all of the Highlander films and the TV series).

David Abramowitz, who wrote the bulk of the Highlander TV series as well as all three of the recent Highlander spinoff films as quoted on [Adrian Paul's blog](http://www.adrianpaul.net/movies/source.html);

> *"The ending of this film takes Highlander into a completely new
>   direction. **It's really good**. I hope that it is the rebirth of the
>   franchise. We'll see."*

Frankly, the closest I could come to finding anyone involved in the film "**disavowing it**" is a [few](http://www.thetimewarriors.co.uk/blog/?p=15757) [quotes](http://www.premiumhollywood.com/2008/03/06/a-chat-with-adrian-paul-%E2%80%9Chighlander-the-source/) from Adrian Paul;

> "The Source unfortunately was weaker [than Endgame] because there were script problems
>   that became apparent when we first started shooting."

and

> *"I
>   thought it [the script] was going to get written by David Abramowitz, and it
>   wasn’t; it was written by somebody else. I think David had some
>   interesting takes on it. He came in to try and help us fix the
>   structural problems we were having in the script on the second
>   version, though.
>
> I think the end was a little confusing, as to what was going to
>   happen and what The Source was about. I think that was a problematic
>   thing we were facing all the way through, and it never really got
>   resolved. Other than that, I think it was another really good work. I
>   think it looked really good; it was a huge-looking film for what we
>   shot it for. **So, basically, I think there are some good things in
>   there, and some stuff that could have been improved**.*

which is hardly the same as a "[word of god](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod)" dismissal of the film as merely a dream.